# activiti - Check if process variable is null

Tags: groovy, alfresco, activiti

I need to check if a process variable is empty so that I can keep a running total of tasks in my process.

I have a local process variable named `totaltasks` of type `integer`.

In my script I simply check if this variable is empty or `null` and then base the rest of the script off this:

```
//If process variable has never been initialised
if( execution.getVariable("totaltasks") === null && execution.getVariable("totaltasks") === 'undefined' ) {
    //set default value to 1 and initialise it
    int totalTasks = 1;
    execution.setVariable("totaltasks", totalTasks);
}
else {
    //otherwise, just increment the current value
    int totalTasks = (int)execution.getVariable("totaltasks");
    totalTasks += 1;
    execution.setVariable("totaltasks", totalTasks);
}
```

The code looks solid but I get the following error in my console:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: problem evaluating script:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: General error during class generation: null.
>   Script6.groovy

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is can't evaluate to true execution.getVariable("totaltasks") === null && execution.getVariable("totaltasks") === 'undefined' . You should use || instead

Comment: Can you switch to JavaScript instead of groovy? Also use if( execution.getVariable("totaltasks")) it should return true as long as the variable has a value different than false. Be careful though as it would return true for an empty string as well!

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code as below to avoid  the `MultipleCompilationErrorsException`.

```
int totalTasksCount = execution.getVariable("totaltasks") as Integer
if(  totalTasksCount && totalTasksCount == 'undefined' ) {
    //set default value to 1 and initialise it
    int totalTasks = 1;
    execution.setVariable("totaltasks", totalTasks);
}
else {
    //otherwise, just increment the current value
    int totalTasks = totalTasksCount
    totalTasks += 1;
    execution.setVariable("totaltasks", totalTasks);
}
```